# Why doesn't value of SwiftUI's @FocusState property change immediately after being set?

Tags: swiftui, properties, state, focus

I've noticed that when I set the value of `@FocusState` property, it doesn't change immediately. I found it by mistake, debugging another issue, but I would like to know why it happens.

`@State` properties, on the other hand, get changed right away after being set.

```
struct FocusStateTest: View {
    
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Tap here first", text: $text)
                .focused($isFocused)
            Text(isFocused ? "Focused" : "Blurred") // <- Works as expected
            Button("Blur") {
                print("Before:", isFocused) // <- when text field is focused, prints true
                isFocused = false
                print("After:", isFocused) // <- prints true - NOT expected
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/focused(_:)):

> When focus moves to the view, the binding sets the bound value to true. If a caller sets the value to true programmatically, then focus moves to the modified view. When focus leaves the modified view, the binding sets the value to false. If a caller sets the value to false, SwiftUI automatically dismisses focus.

This behavior happens because `@FocusState` is not actually a boolean value like in the `@State` var, but a value that tracks the current `focus` state in the `TextField`. That is, `SwiftUI` needs time to remove the focus on the `TextField` and update the `FocusState`. But when you trigger it immediately, `TextField` is still focused, thus, `FocusState` is true as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clarification. In code, it doesn't look so obvious… neither in Apple Docs ;).